# create custom schema in pyspark for reading xml file

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

My XML files look likes this. I want to read Value tag data in pyspark data frame column by using custom schema.Tried my custom schema but it is reading the last tag value(PPP data) and leaving the CCC and FFF details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="QR.xsl"?>
<QQ 
id='123456789'>

<AC>
<At><Name>CCC</Name><Value filename="123456789.csv"><![CDATA[name
cthn,
klop,
]]></Value></At>

<At><Name>FFF</Name><Value filename="123456789"><![CDATA[fff1,fff2
-100,-99.99
-80,-79.64
]]></Value></At>

<At><Name>PPP</Name><Value filename="123456789.csv"><! 
[CDATA[ppp1,ppp2,ppp3,ppp4,ppp5
0,0.10,-1.00,1.00,P,0.00,
]]></Value></At>
</AC>
</QQ>
```

[image]

Refer the code below that i have written in Pyspark.

```
schema = StructType([StructField('AC',StructType([StructField('At', 
StringType())]))])
df= spark.read.format("xml").option("inferschema","true").optio 
n("rowTag","QQ").load("c/xml/test.xml",schema=schema)
df_temp.show(truncate=0)
```

and My output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: schema is nested one, it is picking the last tag data only. Please refer to my code written in pyspark and see the output. You will get an idea about what's happening.

Comment: you can't do `inferschema, true` and `schema=schema` at the same time. do you want it to infer the schema or do you want to use your specified schema?

Comment: also you may want to use array of struct 'At' rather than only a single struct 'At'. otherwise it will only read in 1 struct 'At', which in your case only reads in ppp but not ccc and fff.

Comment: If possible Can you please provide the solution, like how will I define the custom schema using an array of a struct? And I wanted to use the specified schema.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Defined schema like this.

`

```
schema = StructType([StructField("AC",
     ArrayType(StructType([StructField("At", 
  ArrayType(StructType([StructField("Value",StringType())])))]))),])

path = "/mnt/tmp/parser/test.xml"

df_test = 

spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","QQ").load(path,schema=schema)
df_test.show(truncate=0)`
```

answer is comming like :

```
AC                                                                                                                   
[[[[name
cthn,
klop,
], [fff1,fff2
-100,-99.99
-80,-79.64
 ], [ppp1,ppp2,ppp3,ppp4,ppp5
 0,0.10,-1.00,1.00,P,0.00,
]]]]
```